# Substituting query string parameter name in IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, query-string

I was wondering if it is possible to substitute query string parameter names in IIS Rewrite.

For example:

```
http://www.old-site.com/searchresults?pId=77&page=3
```

To

```
http://www.new-site.com/products?pId=77&pageno=3
```

As well as appending the query string (which can contain a whole array of search criteria) to the redirected url, I need to change the parameter name for page to pageno.

An example of my current rule is:

```
<rule name="Search Results" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^searchresults/?$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="page=(\d+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.new-site.com?pageno={C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

... but this ends up giving me http://www.new-site.com/products?pageno=3&pId=77&page=3

My issue is that I don't know which combination of search criteria I could get, but I want to append them to my redirected url replacing page with pageno.

Thanks in advance for any info/advice.